# C++ class constant-value member -- style

Tags: c++, static, enums

My question related to style and underlying efficiency, if there's a difference at all, for effectively static member variables.

Consider:

```
class C {
public:
   static const int const_m = 13;
   static const int const_n = 17;
};

class D {
public:
   enum : int { const_m = 13 };
   enum : int { const_n = 17 };
};
```

In both cases I can write (in a main() fcxn):

```
int main() {
    int cm = C::const_m;
    int cn = C::const_n;

    int dm = D::const_m;
    int dn = D::const_n;
}
```

so the result is the same, and the coding style looks the same. In class C, the value of const_m will be put in the static section of the compiled code, and const_m will refer to the address of this value. In class D, the enum is part of the memory footprint of the class.

I've called g++ -S on both these classes and looked the trivial main() function above. I've also done this with -O0 and -O3 and I can see no different in the asm code. The key ops that correspond to the c++ code above are:

```
movl    $13, -4(%rbp)
movl    $17, -8(%rbp)
movl    $13, -12(%rbp)
movl    $17, -16(%rbp)
```

Is there a consideration that I'm missing when electing to use one style or the other?

Thanks in advance, -Jay

**Edit**

```
class C {
public:
   static constexpr int const_m = 13;
   static constexpr int const_n = 17;
};
```

ensures that `const_m` is compile-time available.

Comment: A more modern comparison would be `static constexpr` instead of `static const`.

Comment: That's very nice. Very explicit. I'm going to amend my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can use the `static const` to size an array for example, because they aren't technically required to be *compile time* constants.

Comment: It works in `gcc` with the above class C and adding an array of `int arr[const_m];` to the class (and a few other uses like that - just to ensure it wasn't a special case).

Comment: If its initializer is a constant expression, then the value is a constant expression. So you're right in general, but in this case it's fine.

Comment: Mark, yours is a nice point, compile-time vs (static-load) run time. I hadn't thought of that. Mats, Nick, good builds.

Comment: I'm 'checking' this answer b/c of the compile-time point, and thanks Mats for your detailed answer. -Jay

Answer (score 3):

Efficiency should definitely be the same for the two choices here. They are "compile time constants", so the compiler will be able to use the value directly without complication.

As to which is "better" from a style perspective, I think it really depends on what you are trying to achieve and what the meaning of the constants are. Enum's are definitely my choice if you have a number of different constants that are closely related, where the `static const int` makes more sense if it's just a single, standalone constant (`max_size` or `magic_file_marker_value`).

As touched on in the other answer, it's possible to come up with a situation where a `static const int something = ...;` is not a compile time constant - e.g.

```
static const time_t seed = time(NULL);
```

This would not allow you to then use it where a compile-time constant is needed [such as array sizes], because although it's a CONSTANT from many perspectives, it is not a compile time known value.

Comment: Thank you for this concrete not-available-at-compile-time example.